# How can I print lines after a regex match in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl

I'm parsing through a text file formatted like below

```
> alpha
apple
airplane
art
> beta
bear
blue
beat
> charlie
cow
cent
coat
```

I'm trying to find entries (`alpha beta charlie`) that has a motif (e.g. "ta"). If the motif is found, then I'm trying to print out the words underneath each entry (`bear blue beat`). 
So in this example, I'd like the following output

```
> beta
bear
blue
beat
```

I've figured out how to print the entry line, but no idea how to print out the lines underneath. Any ideas would be much appreciated.

```
my $motif = "ta";
my $file = "file.pl";
open(INPUT, $file) or die "Can't open file.\n";
parse($motif);

sub parse{
    my ($x) = (@_);
    while(<INPUT>){
        if($_ =~ />*($x)/){
            print $_."\n";
#       if($_ !~ />/){
#           print $_."\n";
        }else{
            next;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So you want to print every line that does *not* start with `">"`, correct?

Comment: @JackManey I'd like to print the line that starts with `>` as well as the words after that `>` that has the match. I've edited my original post with clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you need to keep loop state. The match triggers a "print" state, and a mismatch detriggers it.  So you have something like this?

```
sub parse {
  my ($x) = (@_);
  my $printable = 0

  while (<INPUT>) {
    if ($_ =~ /^>.*($x)/) {
      print $_;
      $printable = 1;
    } elsif ($_ =~ /^>/) {
      $printable = 0;
    } elsif ($printable) {
      print $_;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Appreciate the explanation. I've never seen anything like this before, so it's a new revelation. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Here's another option:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $motif = pop;
local $/ = '>';    # record separator

while (<>) {
    chomp;
    print $/ . $_ if /(?<=\x20).*?$motif/;
}
```

Usage: `perl script.pl data.txt 'ta'`

Output on your data in data.txt:

```
> beta
bear
blue
beat
```

The notation `local $/ = '>'` sets the record separator to `>` instead of the usual `\n`, so each `>` marks the start of a record that's read.  The line your searching has a space immediately after the `>`, and that's what the positive look-behind `(?<=\x20)` attempts to match.

You can redirect output to a file by doing the following: `perl script.pl data.txt 'ta' >output.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you can use a variable (`$print_flag`) to see if you should be printing the line. It's set to 1 (which is evaluated as true) if you get the match that you want and 0 if you match a line that starts with `">"` but that doesn't contain `$motif`.

Try this (warning: untested):

```
use strict;    #Always!
use warnings;  #Always!
my $motif = "ta";
my $file = "file.pl";
open(my $input,"<", $file) or die $!; #two argument open: bad!
parse($motif);

sub parse{
    my ($x) = (@_);
    my $print_flag = 0;
    while(<$input>){

        chomp; #removes trailing EOL character
        if(/^>.*($x)/)   #Don't need $_
        {    
            $print_flag = 1;
        }
        elsif(/^>/)
        {
            $print_flag = 0;
        }

        if($print_flag)
        {
            print "$_\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So it's a like a switch. Haven't seen something like this, but thank you for the clarification! Big revelation to me.

Answer (score 1):

This type of problem seems like a natural for the Perl range operator (more commonly known, in this context, as the "flip-flop" operator).  However, the details of your requirements ended up making it a little more complex than I'd expected:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl    

use strict;
use warnings;

parse('ta');

sub parse {
  my $pattern = shift;

  my $seq;
  while (<DATA>) {
    if ($seq = /^>.*$pattern/ ... (/^>/ && !/^>.*$pattern/)) {
      print unless $seq =~ /E0$/;
    }
  }
}


__DATA__
> alpha
apple
airplane
art
> beta
bear
blue
beat
> charlie
cow
cent
coat
```

Output:

```
> beta
bear
blue
beat
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is always the same number of lines following the match (three) then this hackish "match countdown" idiom would work:

```
 perl -ne '$m=4 if (/^>s/ ); print if ($m-->0);'
```

We use `"4"` in order to match the line plus the number of lines following it (`3`), then we countdown with `$m--` as we proceed to `print`. I use `$m` to mimic a similar option in the shell's `grep`. However I'm actually not certain if this **is** an idiom or what its accepted name would be if it is the case. Probably the `flip-flop` range `...` approach is preferable or more widely used in script - but here is a self-contained script to try using the more hackish approach.

Pass in the number of lines and the pattern to search as arguments:

```
#!perl
use v5.16; # strict & warnings

my $linesafter ; 
my $num = shift ;                                                              
my $pat = shift ;                                                              

while (<DATA>) {                                                               
  $linesafter = $num if ( /^> $pat/ );                                         
  print if ($linesafter-->0); 
}                                                                              

__DATA__                                                                       
> alpha                                                                        
apple                                                                         
airplane                                                                     
art                                                                           
> beta                                                                         
bear                                                                           
blue                                                                          
beat                                                                          
> charlie                                                                     
cow                                                                           
cent                                                                        
coat
```