# How can I print lines that match the pattern that I need in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have some question about this topics:

[How can I print lines after a regex match in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14846045/how-can-i-print-lines-after-a-regex-match-in-perl/34281133#34281133)

I am using the source code and modify the regex to (F) from data.

But when I run, those line that have F also will be pick up. Although I already change the regex to (F). Can anyone help me on this?

This is my data(Input file):

```
 Device#1
 00  000  000 000  1 > beta (F)
 Device#2
 00  000  000 1  000 > beta (F)
 Fail
 Device#3
 00  000  1 000  000 > beta (F)
 57020    0     Main LDO VOUT, IN = 3.5V, OUT = 200u out                    3.480 V        3.480 V        (F) 3.520 V        0.
```

Code that I am using is:

```
my $directory = 'C:\Users\Try';
my $motif = '(F)';

parse($motif);

sub parse{
my ($x) = (@_);  #$x=(F)
print "$x\n";
while(<INPUT>)
{
    if($_ =~ />*($x)/)

        {
        print $_."\n";
        $printable = 1;
        }
    else
        {
      #   print "ELSE\n";
        }
     #   print "FINISH 1 loop\n";
}
}
```

Result that I wish to get:

```
 00  000  000 000  1 > beta (F)
 00  000  000 1  000 > beta (F)
 00  000  1 000  000 > beta (F)
 57020    0     Main LDO VOUT, IN = 3.5V, OUT = 200u out                    3.480 V        3.480 V        (F) 3.520 V        0.
```

The current output I get was as below:

```
 00  000  000 000  1 > beta (F)
 00  000  000 1  000 > beta (F)
 00  000  1 000  000 > beta (F)
 Fail
 57020    0     Main LDO VOUT, IN = 3.5V, OUT = 200u out                    3.480 V        3.480 V        (F) 3.520 V        0.
```

Comment: What is the result you get?

Comment: Hi Jens , i am getting the result
        00  000  000 000  1 > beta (F)
        00  000  000 1  000 > beta (F)
        00  000  1 000  000 > beta (F)
        Fail 
        57020    0     Main LDO VOUT, IN = 3.5V, OUT = 200u out                    3.480 V        3.480 V        (F) 3.520 V        0.

Comment: a extra Fail line on the result. which was not a needed for me .

Comment: Can anyone teach me what does parse works ? 

parse($motif);
sub parse{

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
if($_ =~ />*($x)/)
```

to

```
if($_ =~ />+.*($x)/)
```

so you will get only line with `>` and `(F)` in one line

Explanation:

```
>* mean zero or more `>` so also lines with only a F will be matched (parentheses are Special character in regex)
>+.* means  one or more `>` and after that can be Zero or more character.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) `\b` in your match, so it will not match other things.

Change this:

```
if($_ =~ />*($x)/)
```

to

```
if($_ =~ />*(\b$x\b)/)
```

Comment: @LeowCheesiang: Glad it helped.

Comment: Any place i can chat with u on Perl script?